# Kartik Grid Expandrow childview not filtering from parent data

Tags: yii2

I'm using Kartik expandrow and the parent code works fine. But the child code is not filtering according to the data passed by the the parent.

Code of Kartik Grid in index file -

```
'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
'value' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
},
'detail' => function($model, $key, $index, $column){
    $searchModel = new ExpartiesSearch();
    $searchModel-> parties_district = $model['district'];
    //$searchModel-> billdate = $model['billdate'];
    //$searchModel-> payment_date = $model['payment_date'];
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_exparties', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider
    ]);

},
```

Code of Parent Search query

```
$subQuery1 = (new Query())
    ->select(['parties_district','billdate','sum(billamount) as sale'])
    ->from ('parties')->join('LEFT JOIN','bills','bills.bills_partyname = parties.parties_partyname')
    ->groupby('parties_district')
    ->where('billdate != "NULL"');   

$subQuery2 = (new Query())
    ->select(['district','coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale'])
    ->from('districts')
    ->leftJoin(['sell' => $subQuery1],'sell.parties_district = districts.district');

$subQuery3 = (new Query())
    ->select(['parties_district','payment_date','COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection'])
    ->from('payment')
    ->join('LEFT JOIN','parties','payment.payment_partyname = parties.parties_partyname')
    ->groupby('parties_district');

$query = (new Query())
    ->select(['tsell.district as district','tsell.totalsale as sell','coalesce(tcollection.collection,0) as collection'])
    ->from(['tsell'=> $subQuery2])
    ->leftJoin(['tcollection' => $subQuery3],'tcollection.parties_district = tsell.district');

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    //'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['district'=>SORT_DESC]]
]);

if( !($this->load($params) && $this->validate()) ){
    return $dataProvider;
}

if($this->from_date && $this->to_date){
    $subQuery1->where(['between', 'billdate', $this->from_date, $this->to_date]);
    $subQuery3->where(['between', 'payment_date', $this->from_date, $this->to_date]);
}

return $dataProvider;
```

Code for child query

```
$subQuery1 = (new Query())
    ->select(['bills_partyname','billdate','sum(billamount) as sale'])
    ->from('bills')
    ->groupby('bills_partyname');

$subQuery2 = (new Query())
    ->select(['parties_district','parties_partyname','billdate','coalesce(sell.sale,0) as totalsale'])
    ->from('parties')
    ->leftJoin(['sell' => $subQuery1], 'sell.bills_partyname = parties_partyname')
    ->where('billdate != "NULL"');

$subQuery3 = (new Query())
    ->select(['payment_partyname','payment_date','COALESCE(sum(payment_amount),0) as collection'])
    ->from('payment')
    ->groupby('payment_partyname');

$query = (new Query())
    ->select(['tsell.parties_district as district','tsell.parties_partyname as partyname','tsell.billdate as billdate','tsell.totalsale as sell','COALESCE (tcollection.collection,0) as collection'])
    ->from(['tsell'=> $subQuery2])
    ->leftJoin(['tcollection' => $subQuery3],'tcollection.payment_partyname = tsell.parties_partyname');

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    //'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['district'=>SORT_DESC]]
]);

if( !($this->load($params) && $this->validate()) ){
    return $dataProvider;
}

if($this->from_date && $this->to_date){
    $subQuery1->where(['between', 'billdate', $this->from_date, $this->to_date]);
    $subQuery3->where(['between', 'payment_date', $this->from_date, $this->to_date]);
}

return $dataProvider;
```

There is no error message. Rows in the grid can be expanded by the data in childview does not filter according to the parent. This is same question as [Search data in child view taking input from form in parentview in kartik expandrow in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702745/search-data-in-child-view-taking-input-from-form-in-parentview-in-kartik-expandr)

Comment: I find syntax error on if condition `if($this->from_date && $this->to_date)`

Comment: In my case it's not giving any error. You answered my yesterday's question and this piece of code came up.